# Compare values from two dataframes and merge

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'm working with two dataframes in R:

```
df1 = data.frame(c("A", "B"), c(1, 21), c(17, 29))
colnames(df1) = c("location", "start", "stop")

df1
location    start    stop
A           1        17
B           21       29

df2 = data.frame(c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B"), c(1, 10, 20, 40, 20), c(10, 20, 30, 50, 30), c("x1", "x2","x4", "x5", "x3"))
colnames(df2) = c("location", "start", "stop", "out")

df2
location    start    stop   out
A           1        10     x1
A           10       20     x2
A           20       30     x4
A           40       50     x5  
B           20       30     x3
```

Now I want to check for each row of df1:

- is there a match between 'location' with a 'location' from df2
- if the 'start' value is in the range of start and stop from df2 or if the 'end' value is in the range of start and stop from df2, then the corresponding 'out' value from df2 should be pasted in a new column in df1

This is how the output would look in the case of this example

```
df1_new

location    start    stop    out
A           1        17      x1,x2
B           21       29      x3
```

I've started in R, but I'm stuck at the point where I need to look in the complete dataframe of df2

```
for (i in nrow(df1)) {
   if(df1$location[i] == df2$location # it needs to look for a match in the complete dataframe of df2. I don't know how to do this
   & if (df1$start[i] %in% # it needs to check if the start value lies in the range between df2$start & df2$end
}
```

Comment: Your edit is very incomplete, you added rows to the printout, but not to the code making it. You also neglected to update the output.

Comment: @Frank: I've forgotten to change the code, this is done now. The output stays the same

Comment: Sorry, no, your input now contains an error with quote marks. Try running your code before posting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a data.table way, using `foverlaps`:

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df1))
setDT(df2, key = names(df1))

foverlaps(df1, df2)[, .(out = toString(out)), by=location]

#    location    out
# 1:        A x1, x2
# 2:        B     x3
```

You can get other cols out of the `foverlaps` results if desired:

```
foverlaps(df1, df2)
#    location start stop out i.start i.stop
# 1:        A     1   10  x1       1     17
# 2:        A    10   20  x2       1     17
# 3:        B    20   30  x3      21     29
```

Comment: thanks, this foverlaps function seems useful. However what happens when my df1 has more columns that df2. Should I then set the key only for the columns that are of interest in df1?

Comment: @user1987607 Yes. Alternately, you could skip setting keys and instead use the `by.x`, `by.y` arguments to the function. See `?foverlaps`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to `aggregate` first and then `merge`, i.e.

```
merge(df1, aggregate(out ~ location, df2, toString), by = 'location')

#  location start stop    out
#1        A     1   17 x1, x2
#2        B    21   29     x3
```

Comment: Another option is `df2 %>% group_by(location) %>% summarise(out= toString(out)) %>% inner_join(df1, ., by = "location")`

Comment: @Sotos: I've edited my question slightly, because you misunderstood the question. df2 contains also lines where the start and stop don't match those in df1. So at the end df1_new contains, for line 1, the 'out' values from line1 and 2 from df2, but not from lines 3 and 4. This is because the start and stop range is 1-17, so this overlaps with lines 1 and 2 from df2, but not with lines 3 and 4