# Compare and merge two dataframes

Tags: r

I have the following two dataframes in R:

```
df1 = data.frame(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), c(1, 11, 21, 35, 45), c(6, 20, 30, 40, 60), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
colnames(df1) = c("X", "Y", "Z", "score")

df1 
  X  Y  Z score
1 A  1  6     1
2 A 11 20     2
3 A 21 30     3
4 B 35 40     4
5 B 45 60     5

df2 = data.frame(c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"), c(1, 6, 21, 50, 20, 31, 50, 10), c(5, 20, 30, 60, 30, 40, 60, 20), c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8"))
colnames(df2) = c("X", "Y", "Z", "out")

df2
  X  Y  Z out
1 A  1  5  x1
2 A  6 20  x2
3 A 21 30  x3
4 A 50 60  x4 
5 B 20 30  x5
6 B 31 40  x6
7 B 50 60  x7
8 C 10 20  x8
```

For every row in df1, I want to check:

- is there a match with the value in 'X' and any other 'X' value from df2
- if the above is true: I want to check if the values from 'Y' and 'Z' are in the range of the values 'Y' and 'Z' from df2
- if both are true: then I want to add the value from 'out' to df1.

This is how the output should look like:

```
output = data.frame(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), c(1, 11, 21, 35, 45), c(6, 20, 30, 40, 60), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), c("x1, x2", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5"))
colnames(output) = c("X", "Y", "Z", "score", "out")

  X  Y  Z score    out
1 A  1  6     1 x1, x2
2 A 11 20     2     x2
3 A 21 30     3     x3
4 B 35 40     4     x6
5 B 45 60     5     x7
```

The original df1 is kept with an extra column 'out' that is added.

Line 1 from 'output', contains 'x1, x2' in column 'out'. Why: there is a match between the values in column 'X' and range 1 to 6 overlap with lines 1 and 2 from df2.

I've asked this question before ([Compare values from two dataframes and merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42252663/compare-values-from-two-dataframes-and-merge)) where it is suggested to use the `foverlaps` function. However because of the different columns between df1 and df2 and the extra rows in df2, I cannot make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df1 = data.frame(c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B"), c(1, 11, 21, 35, 45), 
                 c(6, 20, 30, 40, 60), c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(df1) = c("X", "Y", "Z", "score")

df2 = data.frame(c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C"), c(1, 6, 21, 50, 20, 31, 50, 10), 
                 c(5, 20, 30, 60, 30, 40, 60, 20), 
                 c("x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8"), stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(df2) = c("X", "Y", "Z", "out")


df1 %>%
  left_join(df2, by="X") %>%         # join on main column
  rowwise() %>%                      # for each row
  mutate(counter = sum(seq(Y.x, Z.x) %in% seq(Y.y, Z.y))) %>%   # get how many elements of those ranges overlap
  filter(counter > 0) %>%            # keep rows with overlap
  group_by(X, Y.x, Z.x, score) %>%   # for each combination of those columns
  summarise(out = paste(out, collapse=", ")) %>%                # combine out column
  ungroup() %>%
  rename(Y = Y.x,
         Z = Z.x)

# # A tibble: 5 × 5
#       X     Y     Z score    out
#    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
# 1     A     1     6     1 x1, x2
# 2     A    11    20     2     x2
# 3     A    21    30     3     x3
# 4     B    35    40     4     x6
# 5     B    45    60     5     x7
```

The above process is based on `dplyr` package and involves a `join` and some grouping and filtering. If your initial datasets (`df1`, `df2`) are extremely large then the `join` will create an even bigger dataset that will need some time to be created.

Also, note that this process works with `character` and not `factor` variables. The process might convert `factor` variables to `character` if it tries to join `factor` variables with different levels.

I'd suggest you run the chained commands step by step to see how it works and spot if I missed anything that might lead to bugs in the code.

Comment: How can I set the variable 'stringAsFactors = F" for an already existing dataframe?

Comment: First, try to run the same process with `factor` variables, because it might convert them to `character` when it tries to join factors with different levels.

Comment: @AntioniosK: my df1 has 9000 lines, my df2 has 862 lines. Your code worked fluently with a small subset, but with the full data it will take quite a while I suppose ...

Comment: Yes, it will and most likely due to the `rowwise` grouping. It has to get the ranges of every row and compare them.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two possible ways, a) using the newly implemented *non equi* joins feature, and b) `foverlaps` as you'd specifically mentioned that..

a) non-equi joins

```
dt2[dt1, on=.(X, Z>=Y, Y<=Z), 
      .(score, out=paste(out, collapse=",")), 
    by=.EACHI]
```

where `dt1` and `dt2` are data.tables corresponding to `df1` and `df2`. Note that you'll have to revert column names `Z` and `Y` in the result (since the column names come from `dt2` but the values from `dt1`.

Matching rows from `dt2` corresponding to each row is `dt1` is found based on the condition provided to the `on` argument and `.()` is evaluated for *each* of those matching rows (because of `by=.EACHI`).

b) `foverlaps`

```
setkey(dt1, X, Y, Z)
olaps <- foverlaps(dt2, dt1, type="any", nomatch=0L)
olaps[, .(score=score[1L], out=paste(out, collapse=",")), by=.(X,Y,Z)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another options using `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
xx=sqldf('select t1.*,t2.out from df1 t1 left join df2 t2 on t1.X=t2.X and ((t2.Y between t1.Y and t1.Z) or (t2.Z between t1.Y and t1.Z))')
aggregate(xx[ncol(xx)], xx[-ncol(xx)], FUN = function(X) paste(unique(X), collapse=", "))
```