# Update DataFrame Based on Grouped Values from a different DataFrame

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have a dataframe, whose columns need to be updated based on a look-up table. The look-up table is based on groupings set. If there is no match found, the values to be updated will be left blank.

**Here are my input data:**

```
dput(DF_Generated)
structure(list(PO_ID = c("P1234", "P1234", "P1234", "P1234", 
"P1234", "P1234", "P1234", "P2345", "P2345", "P2345", "P3456", 
"P3456", NA, NA), SO_ID = c("S1", "S1", "S1", "S2", "S2", "S2", 
"S3", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S7", NA, "S10", "S10"), F_Year = c(2012, 
2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2014, 2014, 
2015, 2015), Product_ID = c("385X", "385X", "385X", "450X", "450X", 
"900X", "N9X", "3700", "3700", "3800", "A11U", "385X", "2700", 
"3700"), Revenue = c(16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 
35, 35, 35, 100, 100, -50, 20, 50, 20, 100, 10), Quantity = c(1, 
1, 1, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, -10, 20, 20, 5, 40, 20), Location1 = c("MA", 
"NY", "WA", "NY", "WA", "NY", NA, "IL", "IL", NA, "MN", NA, "CA", 
NA), Name = c("N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", NA, "N2", "N2", 
NA, "N3", NA, "N4", NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -14L), .Names = c("PO_ID", "SO_ID", "F_Year", 
"Product_ID", "Revenue", "Quantity", "Location1", "Name"))
```

**Here's my look-up table:**

```
dput(DF_Lookup_2)
structure(list(PO_ID = c("P1234", "P1234", "P1234", "P1234", 
"P1234", "P2345", "P2345", "P3456", NA), SO_ID = c("S1", "S1", 
"S1", "S2", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S7", "S10"), F_Year = c(2012, 
2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2011, 2011, 2014, 2015), Location1 = c("MA", 
"NY", "WA", "NY", "WA", "IL", "IL", "MN", "CA"), Name = c("N1", 
"N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", "N2", "N2", "N3", "N4")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -9L), .Names = c("PO_ID", 
"SO_ID", "F_Year", "Location1", "Name"))
```

**The expected output is:**

```
dput(DFO)
structure(list(PO_ID = c("P1234", "P1234", "P1234", "P1234", 
"P1234", "P1234", "P1234", "P2345", "P2345", "P2345", "P3456", 
"P3456", NA, NA), SO_ID = c("S1", "S1", "S1", "S2", "S2", "S2", 
"S3", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S7", NA, "S10", "S10"), F_Year = c(2012, 
2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2011, 2011, 2012, 2014, 2014, 
2015, 2015), Product_ID = c("385X", "385X", "385X", "450X", "450X", 
"900X", "N9X", "3700", "3700", "3800", "A11U", "385X", "2700", 
"3700"), Revenue = c(16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 
35, 35, 35, 100, 100, -50, 20, 50, 20, 100, 10), Quantity = c(1, 
1, 1, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, -10, 20, 20, 5, 40, 20), Location1 = c("MA", 
"NY", "WA", "NY", "WA", "NY", NA, "IL", "IL", NA, "MN", NA, "CA", 
"CA"), Name = c("N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", "N1", NA, "N2", 
"N2", NA, "N3", NA, "N4", "N4")), .Names = c("PO_ID", "SO_ID", 
"F_Year", "Product_ID", "Revenue", "Quantity", "Location1", "Name"
), row.names = c(NA, 14L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Logic:**

The look-up is done based on three columns: `PO_ID`,`SO_ID`,`F_Year`. If the match is found, the entries are overwritten only if the data frame **requires** an update. For instance, columns `Location1` and `Name` with rows such that `PO_ID` = `P1234`, `SO_ID` = `S1` and `F_Year` = `2012` should not be overwritten because their values already exist in the lookup table. However, the entries in columns `Location1` and `Name` for rows such that `PO_ID` = `NA`, `SO_ID` = `S10` and `F_Year` = `2015` would need to be updated with a valid value from the look-up table, which is `CA` and `N4` respectively. I tried using `Data.Table` but my code below overwrites all entries, which is incorrect.

I read [Compare and merge two dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274151/compare-and-merge-two-dataframes/42282538#42282538) thread, and tried to do this, but the code overwrites existing entries that I need not look up.

Here's my code:

```
data.table::setDT(DF_Generated)
data.table::setDT(DF_Lookup_2)
data.table::setkey(DF_Generated,PO_ID,SO_ID,F_Year)
data.table::setkey(DF_Lookup_2,PO_ID,SO_ID,F_Year)

DF_Generated[DF_Lookup_2,on=c("PO_ID","SO_ID","F_Year"),c("Location1","Name"):=list(i.Location1,i.Name)]
```

I have two questions:

**Question: 1)** I am using `Data.Table` because my actual data are big. So, I am looking for `data.table`-based solution. How could I fix my `data.table` code?

**Question 2)** I am open to `dplyr` as well, if that's recommended way.

However, for my learning, I'd really appreciate if you could help me with both the solutions. I am a beginner, and still learning these two packages.

Comment: @akrun - Thanks for your help. If you run the above code, you will see that `Location1` will be all `WA` (different from the original data set `DF_Generated`. Please see the expected output in columns `Location1`  and `Name`. Does that help? Maybe I didn't follow your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another of doing this is to join (by condition) to `DF_Lookup_2` and then assign in back to `DF_Generated`. The reason for doing this the other way around is because in and `X[Y]` join, the resulting join is of length `Y` hence, a join of type `DF_Lookup_2[DF_Generated]` will give us the desired length. Then, we can just put it back into `DF_Generated` as is.

```
DF_Generated[is.na(Location1) | is.na(Name), c("Location1", "Name"):= 
               DF_Lookup_2[DF_Generated[is.na(Location1) | is.na(Name)], 
                           .(Location1, Name), on = .(PO_ID, SO_ID, F_Year)]]


identical(DF_Generated, setDT(DFO))
## [1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create two new columns with when joining `on` 'PO_ID', 'SO_ID', and 'F_Year', then update the old column where there is NA using `set`

```
setDT(DF_Generated)[setDT(DF_Lookup_2), c("Location1N", "NameN") := list(i.Location1, 
                               i.Name),on = .(PO_ID, SO_ID, F_Year)]
nm1 <- c("Location1", "Name")
nm2 <- paste0(nm1, "N")
for(j in seq_along(nm1)){
 set(DF_Generated, i = which(is.na(DF_Generated[[nm1[j]]])), j=nm1[j], 
                     value = DF_Generated[[nm2[j]]][is.na(df1[[nm1[j]]])])
}
DF_Generated[, (nm2) := NULL][]

identical(setDT(DFO), DF_Generated)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I have two follow-up questions, if you don't mind: a) Do you think `dplyr` will be simpler? b) Do you think the performance of this code will be good ? I am asking this because in my original data set, I have about 100M rows, and ~28 columns. I am yet to run your code on the original data set because it will take time for me to customize above code. I am a beginner, and don't have much clue. Hence, I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: @watchtower  There is a `coalesce` function in `tidyverse`, but if there are duplicates then the `left_join` will not work

Comment: Thanks so much. Very respectfully, I am getting error not sure why. `"Error in data.table::set(DF_Generated, i =which(is.na(DF_Generated[[nm1[j]]])),  :  RHS of assignment to existing column 'Location1' is zero length but not NULL. If you intend to delete the column use NULL. Otherwise, the RHS must have length > 0; e.g., NA_integer_. If you are trying to change the column type to be an empty list column then, as with all column type changes, provide a full length RHS vector such as vector('list',nrow(DT)); i.e., 'plonk' in the new column. ` Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: @watchtower Is this based on the example in your post or the original dataset.  Would it be due to the package version?  I am using data.table_1.10.0

Comment: @ akrun - Thanks for your follow-up. This is based on the example in the post. I haven't touched the original dataset yet. I am using data.table 1.10.4. I ran David's example above, and had no issues. Somehow, when I run your code above, it breaks. Not sure why.

Comment: @watchtower  May be there is a new feature in 10.4 which breaks it.  I am not sure  I have to update it

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way I can test your code on an older package? I googled this and couldn't find any info. I'd appreciate your thoughts. I am curious.

Comment: @watchtower  Please go ahead and use DavidArenburg's code if this has a problem in the new version